# backtrace function inside shared libraries

Tags: c++, linux, stack-trace, x86-64, backtrace

I'm trying to obtain and save a stack trace to a file after I get `SEGSEGV` inside my shared library. The shared library is a plugin for a closed-source product. All this works on production and I don't have a direct access to it.

My code catches `SIGSEGV` signal, prints stack-trace and exits. I have something like this:

> /opt/ecelerity/libexec/site/ec_attachextensions.so [0x2aecc2019f11]
>   /opt/ecelerity/libexec/site/ec_attachextensions.so [0x2aecc2019f11]
>   /opt/ecelerity/libexec/site/ec_attachextensions.so [0x2aecc2019fee]
>   /opt/ecelerity/libexec/site/ec_attachextensions.so [0x2aecc201a587]
>
> /opt/ecelerity/sbin/ecelerity [0x501235]
>
> /opt/ecelerity/sbin/ecelerity(sieve_seng_execute+0x82) [0x506d32]
>   /opt/ecelerity/libexec/validate/sieve.so [0x2aecc2862c9e]
>   /opt/ecelerity/sbin/ecelerity(validate_data+0xa5) [0x4a90d5]
>   /opt/ecelerity/sbin/ecelerity(esmtp_message_factory+0x154e) [0x46eace]
>   /opt/ecelerity/sbin/ecelerity(schedule_event_and_dispatch+0x6a) [0x49c59a]

The problem is that I cannot have the names of functions and offsets inside them for a shared 
library. As I understand I can find function name/file name for a given address with help of
addr2line utility after I will find library offset in `/proc/$PID/maps`.

After that I'm executing something like that:

```
addr2line -e /opt/ecelerity/libexec/site/ec_attachextensions.so (LIBRARY_OFFSET_FROM_MAPS_FILE - 0x2aecc2019f11)
```

Where `0x2aecc2019f11` is the address from the stack trace above. I was wondering is there any way I can get function names in a stack trace without touching maps file? In other words how can I program it? Would `dladdr` help here (`dladdr` unable to get function names from addresses provided by `backtrace` function in my case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the backtrace code uses approximately the same mechanism as dladdr to determine function names.

if your library is built using either a linker map file (that defines what is being exported, and can be used to restrict the visibility of all other items), or the `-fvisibility=hidden` with explicit visible symbols, then it obscures the symbols so that they will not appear in the backtrace output.

Workarounds are to compile without using a map file that restricts the visibility of all the symbols in the library, or to build with the `-fvisibility=default`. That will get backtrace to work without any effort on your behalf.

To get it to work without doing this, you need to load up the local symbol table from the .so and determine the symbol locations using a mechanism similar to addr2line. The mechanism to do this is to make use of [`libelf1`](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Libelf). to read the local symbol table.

... This of course requires that the table has not been stripped from the file. If that is the case, then none of these tricks matter as the .so simply does not come with the information.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the signal handler read /proc/self/maps for you.

Or you can output the absolute address of some function which you can then use as a point of comparison to find the library offset.

But I would not be surprised if there is a dynamic linker function which would give you the base address - you can check the docs for that.